# UItableview section order

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sorting

I am having trouble using sectioned tableview. Sectioned table view is sorting my data and displaying in asc or desc order. I have fetched data from the database using order by clause and now want to display as it is, but tableview is messing up with my sorted data. Suggest me ways to avoid this.

this is the data

```
{
    Today =     (
                {
            AlertTime = 1;
            DateFormatWithAMPM = "11-16-2013 01:45 PM";
            DateOfTask = Today;
            FolderId = 2;
            FolderName = Routine;
            FolderStatus = 0;
            Notes = "Task 2";
            Status = 1;
            TaskDate = "2013-11-16 13:45:45";
            TaskDateFormatted = "11-16-2013 13:45";
            TaskId = 2;
            description = "Task 2";
        }
    );
    Tomorrow =     (
                {
            AlertTime = 2;
            DateFormatWithAMPM = "11-17-2013 01:45 PM";
            DateOfTask = Tomorrow;
            FolderId = 2;
            FolderName = Routine;
            FolderStatus = 0;
            Notes = "Notes 1 of 1";
            Status = 1;
            TaskDate = "2013-11-17 13:45:44";
            TaskDateFormatted = "11-17-2013 13:45";
            TaskId = 1;
            description = "Task 1 of 1";
        }
    );
}
```

but when the tableview loads it shows "tomorrow" section first and "today" section in the end.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create sections?

Comment: Its very hard to help you without more information. Normally you implement a numberOfSectionsInTableView and a numberOfRowsInSection delegate. The process is pretty straight-forward **if** you sorted the data server side.  Make sure that when returning the data you swap the sections. Since section 1 one comes before section 2, you can sort you like…